# making autoclick on tampermonkey javascript

Tags: javascript

trying to make an auto delete rows script without deleting some specific lines with orden de venta #SO10100

```
let delete_nums = ["#SO202771", "#SO202772", "#SO202773"];
function getRowsToDelete() {
  // Initialize an array that's going to contain all the rows to be deleted
  let delete_rows = [];
  // Get the element that contains all the rows
  const ordenDeVenta = document.getElementsByClassName("uir-machine-row");
  // Loop through all these rows
  Array.from(ordenDeVenta).forEach(row => {
    // Find the cell that contains the order no.
    const cellWithNum = row.children[x];
    // Go through each order no that has to be deleted
    delete_nums.forEach(num => {
      // If it's in the cell
      if (cellWithNum.textContent.contains(num)) {
        // Add the row to the array
        delete_rows.push(row);
      }
    })
  })
  // Return the array with rows to be deleted
  return delete_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you automatically want to make such as click on the element (as your title said), you can use:

```js
row.click();
```

You should have an event on the row. Else, if it's on a button, search the button itself.

If you want to remove a line, you can use `element.remove()` that will do the job:

```js
function del(id) {
   document.getElementById("row-" + id).remove();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-1" onclick="del(1)">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-2" onclick="del(2)">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here, everything is simplified. In you case, instead of using `getElementById` you are using children element of `getElementsByClassName`.